# React how to inject js dependency at runtime

Tags: reactjs, google-places-api

So need to following dependency in my application:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY></script>
```

Problem is I don't have my key until runtime. I am not sure what the "react" way of injecting this at runtime would be? I realize i could get the head element and add the html in the window onload event like below:

```
document.head.append('<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY></script>');
```

Is this the best way to do this?

Comment: have you tried this package https://github.com/google-map-react/google-map-react#examples ???

Comment: Not trying to install any npm stuff unless i have to

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to add on your componentDidMount or useEffect?

```js
componentDidMount() {
      const script = document.createElement('script');
      const key = <GET_YOUR_API_KEY>
      script.type = 'text/javascript';
      script.src = `https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=${key}`;
      script.id = 'someID';
      document.body.appendChild(script);
      script.addEventListener('load',() => console.log('map loaded'))
  }
```